# how do I know tomcat is running on Windows

Tags: windows, tomcat, tomcat6

I'm on Windows, went to `%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\` and ran startup.

I did see another commandline window popup and tomcat was loading some webapps that were there before (I had run webapp inside my IDE before that, now wanted to try from commandline). Then the window disappeared. I tried the address `http://localhost:8080/manager/html`, it's not loaded.

So how do I know tomcat is running on Windows. I tried Task Manager didn't see it there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should appear as a `javaw.exe` process. If you have multiple java apps running, you might have to keep an eye on how many are running to see if you gain 1 more after launching.

Answer (score 3):

You can use WMIC.exe to get all the information that task manager would give you, INCLUDING the full command line of each process on the system.   Then, you can use "FIND" to grep the output of that command and find a specific instances if you have more than one.

```
wmic.exe process list brief | find /i "tomcat"
```

To answer your specific question though, try starting Tomcat and redirecting the output to a log file and then examine it for errors:

```
   C:\Temp\Tomcat6> startTomcat.bat>console.log&ECHO console.log
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using [TCPView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx) to determine what processes are listening on what IPs/ports.

Answer (score 1):

Since tomcat 9 you can recognize it in Processes with name "Tomcat9w" and in Services "Tomcat9"

Answer (score 1):

Powershell:

```
get-service "*apache*"
```

You can also enable telnet client feature. And then open command line and type `telnet hostname port` and press enter. If cmd turns blank then it means that port is open and service is listening. You can then type `/GET` and press enter to send the get request.

Answer (score 0):

a variation of @djangofan's answer using `wmic` exclusively:

```
wmic process where "commandline like '%tomcat%' and name='java.exe'"
```

and if you want to kill that process, just add `delete`

```
wmic process where "commandline like '%tomcat%' and name='java.exe'" delete
```

note that the `where` filter is similar to SQL in concept, and the `like` clause functions the same as SQL`like` so you can go to town with the substring matching as you see fit.